# Making one column in DataGridView read only

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Within my program i have included a datagridview that is filled when the form loads. When it first loads i have set the whole form to read-only. However if the user then wants to edit the data within it they can click an edit button i have included on the form, this has the code:

```
datagrdSnippets.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True 'Allows user to delete rows
datagrdSnippets.ReadOnly = False 'Allows user to edit cells within the data grid
```

However i do not want one of the columns within the datagridview to be made editable, what code can i use to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Column1.ReadOnly = True
        Column2.ReadOnly = True
        Column3.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

set readonly true your desired column on form load event

Comment: The datagridview is set to read only on load, i only want to make it editable when the edit button is clicked, which i have included the code for above, i just need the line of code needed so my whole datagridview is editable apart from one column

Answer (score 2):

Me, I have data source from database in my `dataGridView` so I use for loop to get the exact column address that I want to make `ReadOnly=true` and the rest is `ReadOnly=false`

**Code:**

```
For i = datagridview1.columns.count - 1 to 0 Step -1

  If i = (YourSpecificColumnAddress) Then
     Datagridview1.columns(i).ReadOnly=true
  Else  
     Datagridview1.columns(i).ReadOnly=false
  End if

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      datagrdSnippets.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
      datagrdSnippets.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
      datagrdSnippets.Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dataGrid.Columns(index).ReadOnly = True
 dataGrid.Columns(index).ReadOnly = True

 dataGrid.Columns("column_name").ReadOnly = True
```